# drop label from metrics prometheus

Tags: regex, prometheus

I have the metric below and I want to drop the label **"exported_namespace="test"** and I am using the prometheus **relabel_config** but I'm not sure if the config will work properly:

```
"kube_pod_status_ready{condition="false", env="test", exported_namespace="test", instance="10.69.19.17:8080", job="kube-state-metrics", namespace="test", pod="test-1-deploy", uid="1asdadasaas"}
```

**prometheus scrape config**

```
- source_labels = [exported_namesapce]
  separator: ,
  action: labeldrop
  regex: (.*)
  replacement: $1
```

Answer (score 5):

Please note that you must use `metric_relabel_configs` instead of `relabel_configs` if you want apply relabeling on the collected metrics. See [this article](https://www.robustperception.io/life-of-a-label/) for details.

If you want to drop a label with a particular value from the collected metric, then use the following relabeling rule at [metric_relabel_configs](https://prometheus.io/docs/prometheus/latest/configuration/configuration/#metric_relabel_configs) section of the needed [scrape_config](https://prometheus.io/docs/prometheus/latest/configuration/configuration/#scrape_config):

```yaml
- source_labels: [exported_namespace]
  regex: test
  target_label: exported_namespace
  replacement: ""
```

This relabeling rule substitutes the `exported_namespace="test"` label with `exported_namespace=""` label, which, in turn, is automatically removed by Prometheus, since it contains an empty label value. You can play with this relabeling rule at [this page](https://play.victoriametrics.com/select/accounting/1/6a716b0f-38bc-4856-90ce-448fd713e3fe/metric-relabel-debug).

If you need just dropping the `exported_namespace` label with any value, then use the following relabeling rule:

```yaml
- action: labeldrop
  regex: exported_namespace
```

Note that this rule will drop any value for `exported_namespace` label. For example, both `exported_namespace="test"` and `exported_namespace="foo"` will be dropped.

Update: if you use [vmagent](https://docs.victoriametrics.com/vmagent/), then you can use `if` filter for dropping label with the particular value. For example, the following rule drops only `exported_namespace="test"` label:

```yaml
- if: '{exported_namespace="test"}'
  regex: exported_namespace
  action: labeldrop
```

See [these docs](https://docs.victoriametrics.com/vmagent/#relabeling-enhancements) for more information about `if` filter.

Answer (score 0):

You can do:

```
writeRelabelConfigs:
  - regex: exported_namespace
    action: labeldrop
```

OR

```
writeRelabelConfigs:
  - action: labeldrop
    regex: exported_namespace
```